# Different objects of a class with different access levels

Tags: c#

There was a question asked by interviewer for C#:

**One public class having 5 public members. A person wants an object which consumes 2
members and another to consume all 5 members. How to achieve this ?**

I could not understand this. Can anyone please help what did it meant ?
What would be a situation where something as above would be required ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter there was no code or anything. this was directly asked as such. what i believe is that maybe he was asking that one object will have access to few members while other will have to all members. I am still guessing.

Comment: That depends entirely on what the asker meant by "consume", unlikely you'll get a canonical answer here...

Comment: Apparently you were supposed to say that you'd create a wrapper that exposes only the two members. Or not, because it's hard to tell.

Comment: If by *"consume 2 members"* they mean *"restrict to being able to consume only two members"* (which is absolutely not clear), then you can expose two members through an interface, create a wrapper or extract the two members to a base class. But the members are not consumed by persons anyway. They are accessed by some code.

Comment: Minimal solution: have the class implement an interface that declares the members the first "person" is allowed to access. When giving that person an object of the class, make sure it is typed as that interface. The other "person" can access the class directly.

Comment: The right answer to that question is "Sorry, what exactly do you mean?"  Sometimes an interviewer is looking to start a conversation, not get a precise (or concise) answer (when I worked at Microsoft, one of my colleagues would ask deliberately "somewhat incorrect" questions to see how the interviewee would respond - but only to strongly experienced candidates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's hard to tell if this is what the interviewer wanted to hear. You should have asked what exactly he means with *Person* and *consume*.

I guess he wanted to hear that you understand for what interfaces are:

```
public interface IPerson: IHaveName
{
    DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
    string MainAddress {get;set;}
    string MainPhoneNumber {get;set;}
}

public interface IHaveName
{
    string FirstName {get;set;}
    string LastName {get;set;}
}

public class Person: IPerson
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
    public string MainAddress {get;set;}
    public string MainPhoneNumber {get;set;}
}
```

Now you can pass the `Person` to a method that needs to consume the whole `Person` or a method that just needs to consume the Name:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Person p = new Person(); // skip initialization
    ConsumePerson(p);
    ConsumeNames(p);
}

public static void ConsumePerson(IPerson person)
{
    // do something with the whole Person object
}

public static void ConsumeNames(IHaveName name)
{
   // do something with just the FirstName/LastName
}
```